# Shorthand to Extend Range / Array with Elements on either side

Tags: list-manipulation

Is there a short hand for adding a value to a vector? E.g.,

```
{.01,Range[.5,5,.5],10}
```

gives

```
{0.01, {0.5, 1., 1.5, 2., 2.5, 3., 3.5, 4., 4.5, 5.},10}
```

but what I really want is

```
{0.01, 0.5, 1., 1.5, 2., 2.5, 3., 3.5, 4., 4.5, 5.,10}
```

Comment: `Prepend[Range[.5,5,.5],.01]`?

Comment: I suppose... seems strange there's not a "expand" shorthand of sorts

Comment: E.g., `{.01,...Range[.5,5,.5],10}`

Comment: The operation you're looking for is `Apply[Sequence]`. It has no input alias. Best you can really get is `Sequence @@`

Comment: you can do `Flatten@{.01, Range[.5, 5, .5], 10, Range[5]}`; or, to save a character, `## & @@@ {.01, Range[.5, 5, .5], 10, Range[5]}`.

Comment: Oh my... yes... that is what I am looking for thanks so much!

Comment: Another option, although admittedly strange: `ArrayPad[Range[.5, 5, .5], 1, {10, 0.01}]`.